# Set css multiple class runtime in tag in asp.netcore mvc page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a cshtml page where at page level i have a variable active having css class names. I want to set this variable in a button tag in the same page.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Title";
    var active ="nav-link active";   
}   

<button class=@active id="nav-experience-tab" ... ...
```

But the output is:

```
<button class="nav-link" active="" id="nav-experience-tab"
```

Second way:

```
var active ="class='nav-link active'";
<button @active id="nav-experience-tab" ... ...
```

output is:

```
<button class="'nav-link" active&#x27;="" id="nav-experience-tab"
```

Third way:

```
var active ="class=nav-link active";
<button @active id="nav-experience-tab" ... ...
```

output is:

```
<button class="nav-link" active="" id="nav-experience-tab"
```

Is there anyway to get the below?

```
<button class="nav-link active" id="nav-experience-tab"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set like this:

```
@{
    var active ="nav-link active";
}

<button class="@active" >click</button>
```

Demo

[image]